# Redirecting C++ Program contents to cmd.exe

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pipe, createprocess

I am required to call a utility program(`special.exe`) thousands of times with certain parameters which are decided from within my C++ program.

Presently, I am using `CreateProcess()` to run the utility program(`special.exe`) and using pipe handles to get back the results. This is within a loop. So, effectively, my program has a huge overhead as it creates and destroys thousands of child processes.

Pseudo-Code (Presently) :

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{ 
    i) set all necessary attr for createprocess()
    ii) str = "D:\\special.exe " + to_string(i)
   iii) CreateProcess(NULL, str(), ...)
    iv) collect back results
    iv) close all handles
}
```

Now, what I intend to do is use `CreateProcess()` to open `cmd.exe` once and then run the utility program(`special.exe`) from there as and when required. I want to know if there is a way to pass strings from my main *C++* program to the child `cmd.exe` process.

Pseudo-Code (Intent) :

```
i) set all necessary attr for createprocess
ii) CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd.exe", ...)

for(i=0;i<n; i++)
{
    iii) str = "special.exe " + to_string(i)
    iv) pass str to cmd.exe process and execute
    v) collect back results
}
vi) close all handle
```

I think this might be a faster approach as it deals with lesser process creations.

Is this thinking right? And, is this possible? Please share your insights and some sample codes as hints if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you imagine how cmd.exe starts commands? Well it boils down to `CreateProcess`... So your *faster* approach will just add the complexity of identifying the output corresponding to each command.

Comment: It's a common fallacy for people who are used to using console to want to push everything through cmd. But once you are writing programs then you don't need a command interpreter. You can create new processes directly. What you need to do is create one process and then use IPC to communicate with it.

Comment: It also depends on how your "special.exe" behaves.   If it starts, reads a small set of inputs, processes them, and unconditionally terminates then you will need to run it multiple times - which means launching a process every time.   If  the program loops based on input (e.g. reads some input, processes that input, then loops back until it obtains input that directs it to terminate) then you should be able to run it once to process all your data.

Comment: *"it creates and destroys thousands of child processes"* - That may well be the case. It is unclear why you believe that creating and destroying thousands of child processes plus one (cmd.exe) would be any faster than creating and destroying thousands of child processes. *"Is this thinking right?"* - No.

Comment: Thanks @all! Now I have a clear idea of the overheads I'll have. Anyway, I have sought out to write the utility on my own so that I don't have to call it from my program.